# Java многопоточность. Добавить данные в определенный поток

Tags: java, многопоточность, users

Всем доброго времени суток. Имеется телеграм бот, который делаю чисто для себя, чтобы "поднять скилл". И взбрело в голову добавить к нему многопоточность.
**Суть в следующем:** Имеется телеграм бот. Пользователь пишет какую-либо команду (типа /start, /reg и тд.) Каждое сообщение приходит в программу в виде объекта Update u. И уже из этого объекта получаем всю необходимую информацию (id пользователя, сообщение и тд.).
**Задача:** Для каждого нового пользователя создаем отдельный поток и затем следим за тем, кто нам пишет и именно в нужный поток отправляем эти данные.
На данный момент я пытался сделать название потока согласно id пользователя, но при проверке на эквивалентность названий все нити начали называться null, вместо id, хотя имя нити в конструктор приходит правильное. А если убрать проверку, то нить называется согласно id первого пользователя. И если напишет второй человек, то новый поток начинается, но название его остается, как у прежнего, т.е. новая нить создается, но со старым названием. Прилагаю метод,который ответственен за обработку приходящих сообщений,а так же за создание новой нити или передачу данных (по задумке) в старую нить. И класс, который унаследован от Thread и отвечает за обработку данных.

```
    public synchronized void onUpdateReceived(Update e) {

        // System.out.println("updateIdArray.size() = " + updateIdArray.size());
        updateIdArray.add(new UpdateId(e.getMessage().getChatId(), e));
        int count = updateIdArray.size();
        chatId = e.getMessage().getChatId();
        if (setId.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Long.toString(chatId) = " + Long.toString(chatId));
            thread = new ThreadForUser(Long.toString(chatId), count);
            thread.start();
            thread.setChatId(chatId);
            setId.add(chatId);
        }
        if (setId.contains(chatId)) {
            //Нужно решить проблему с тем, чтобы данные добавлялись именно в нужный поток с Id
            if (("Thread-" + chatId).equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())) {
                ThreadForUser.setIndex(count);
                thread.setChatId(chatId);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Long.toString(chatId) = " + Long.toString(chatId));
            thread2 = new ThreadForUser(Long.toString(chatId), count);
            thread2.start();
            thread2.setChatId(chatId);
            setId.add(chatId);
        }

    }



       public class ThreadForUser extends Thread {
    private Message message;
    private Long chatId;
    private ArrayList<String> textMessage;
    private int counter = 0;
    private boolean isFinish = true;
    private int index;


    public ThreadForUser(String name, int index) {
        super(name);
        this.index = index;
    }

    public static String getMessageTextForUser() {
        return messageTextForUser;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public static void setIndex(int index) {
        index = index;
    }

    public Long getChatId() {
        return chatId;
    }

    public void setChatId(Long chatId) {
        this.chatId = chatId;
    }

    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("Thread-" + getChatId().toString());
        System.out.println("Start thread! " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        textMessage = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (isFinish) {
            try {
                    getIndex();
                    getChatId();
                    message = CostsBotTest.updateIdArray.get(index-1).getEvent().getMessage();
                    textMessage.add(message.getText() + " / ");
                    System.out.println(textMessage);
                    CostsBotTest.updateIdArray.remove(index-1);

                    if (textMessage.size() > 3) {
                        textMessage.add(" id = " + chatId);
                        textMessage.removeAll(textMessage);
                        CostsBotTest.setId.remove(chatId);
                        counter = 0;
                        System.out.println("Cleared!");
                    }

            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                //System.out.println(e);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста,как можно реализовать мою задумку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм, странное решение. Зачем искать нужный поток, извращаясь с его названием, если можно использовать некий буфер - как вариант создать потокобезопасную мапу с ключем chatId и значением count.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Integer> chatIdCountMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public synchronized void onUpdateReceived(Update e) {
//...
        chatIdCountMap.put(chatId, count);
//...
    }

    public void run() {
//...
        int index = chatIdCountMap.get(chatId);
//...
    }
```

Comment: Не совсем понял,для чего в мапу класть значение  **count = udateIdArray.size();** , если это значение всегда равно 1,потому что после каждого полученного и обработанного события в классе **ThreadForUser** оно удаляется **(CostsBotTest.updateIdArray.remove(index-1);)** Или что вы имели в виду? (приношу свои извинения за  форматирование текста, я совсем недавно тут.

Comment: Как я понял по коду вам нужно в нужный поток передать нужное значение. Если да, то это абстракное решение, ключ и значение можно использовать любые.